# Remove debug popup window in IE9 - EasyXDM

Tags: easyxdm

I am using easyXDM to make cross domain calls within a web application, but in IE9 I keep getting a popup with the logs. How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the easyXDM javascript file you include to `easyXDM.js` not `easyXDM.debug.js`